# QtWebkit QWebView setUrl Memory Leak

Tags: c++, qt, webkit, qtwebkit

The virtual memory usage of my simple qtwebkit application increases forever.
My qtwebkit app simply loops webView->setUrl(QUrl(QStringLiteral("about:blank")), as follows,

```
QWebView* webView = new QWebView(centralWidget);
webView->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("webView"));
webView->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, width, height));

while (true)
{
    webView->setUrl(QUrl(QStringLiteral("about:blank")));
    msleep(1); // sleep 1 millisecond
}
```

I think the memory usage should be stable in this case, however, the result is not.
What's the matter? some kind of clearing is required to use setUrl() multiple times?

- Qt version : 5.4.1
- OS : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is normal for `QtWebKit` and will be never fixed because it is recommended to use `QtWebEngine` now.

About memory leaks: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-36530

There is a number of techniques you can use to clear memory like:

```
QWebSettings::globalSettings()->clearMemoryCaches();
```

See here: http://forum.qt.io/topic/10832/memory-size-increases-per-page-load

But usually this is not very helpful and you will have memory leaks as far as you will use `QtWebKit`. If you are developing new project and your platform supports [QtWebEngine](https://wiki.qt.io/QtWebEngine), you should think about using it.

Comment: Did  you mean this memory leak comes from Qt? Then, in other webkit ports such as GTK+ or EFL, the same sample code will not incur the memory leak?

Comment: I don't know about GTK+ or EFL. You asked about Qt Web Kit and I answered because I worked with it a lot. Other implementations may have this bug or may not.

Comment: I am wondering whether this memory leak is produced by webkit or not. If webkit is the cause, changing webkit port would not help. If Qt is reponsible for this memory leak, I could consider other webkit ports, or other webkit forks such as blink which is the root of QtWebEngine as far as I know.

Comment: Probably the best way is to take other implementation and check? Or at least edit your question or ask another one if you want to receive answer here